# Facebook Page Tab App - like page before accessing app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook Page Tab App up and running and has been running for about a year.  I need to collect more likes for our business page as opposed to the app page.  Is there a way to ask new users of the app to like a page before they have access to the app?
Many thanks,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about increasing the likes of the fan page

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api)

Comment: I'm not au fait with Facebook, but is it ethical to force someone to "like" something before they've used your app? They can't make an assessment before they've used it, and they may end up not liking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking for is called "Fan gate" - google it and you will find multiple example. In 2 words - when page is loaded, you need to check if user is logged in, and if user liked the app - and then you either redirect them to the "real" app page, or make certain div visible, or whatever you want. But if that's not the case - then you keep Please like us" div displayed, and it covers all your content. See this page for example: https://www.facebook.com/redbull/app_113185218710496

and here is a link to similar SO question: [How to create a fan / like gate on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560385/how-to-create-a-fan-like-gate-on-facebook)